# Facebook authentication getting blocked in chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook-authentication

Facebook login (authentication) form is getting blocked in Google Chrome (not all the time, but sometimes).

HTML content for fb

`<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='facebook'><img src='fblogimage'></a>`

in .js file

```
$("#facebook").click(function ()
{
    Facebook.authenticate(function () { 
       Login.hidePopup();
    });
});

Facebook.authenticate = function (callback)
{
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected')
        {
            // -- success process
        }
        else
        {
            FB.login(function (loginResponse)
            {
                if (loginResponse.status === 'connected')
                {
                    Facebook.setUserName();
                    Facebook.fbApi(loginResponse, callback);
                }
            },
            {
                scope: 'user_friends, publish_stream, email, user_location, 
                user_mobile_phone'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**It's working in FF and IE, but not working in Google Chrome (popup block)**

Please help to solve.

Comment: Do you have DoNotTrackMe or something similar blocking Facebook cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in multiple browsers, not just Chrome. It turns out that you have to **invoke the login popup from a button click**.

Here's a quote from [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#logindialog) (emphasis added):

> As noted in the reference docs for this function, it results in a
>   popup window showing the Login dialog, and therefore **should only be
>   invoked as a result of someone clicking an HTML button (so that the
>   popup isn't blocked by browsers)**.

Your code could be having issues due to using `<a href='javascript:void(0);'` instead of a `<button>` or a valid link (like `<a href="#">` or something similar).

Hope this helps someone!